# How does one deal with trivial changes in a working tree using Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I often find myself in a position where I have one or two uncommitted changes in my staging area. Sometimes, these changes do not warrant a commit. Usually, the reasoning for this is because the changes made are only modifications to comments or commenting out code temporarily.

> I have a WPF app that has exceptions caught at the top level using an event subscription. I have commented out the line subscribing to the event so that I can have proper debug info for all exceptions thrown.

How can I make git treat my changes as though they are already committed without having to create a commit just for the changes?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "reset the head".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. The whole point of a VCS is to **NOT** overlook any changes. Never, without any exception.

Instead, reset your local-only file changes as required before committing the 'real' ones.

Comment: Thanks. So I should undo the commented lines? Should I be making separate commits for adding documentation?

Comment: I think it's best to have separate baby commits for every set of related changes (e.g. 'Comments update'). You can then roll back your local file changes that you don't want to go into the repo. The problem is, that things quickly can get messy when you have various different changes in one file. Therefore, it's wise to do too much at once...